# How to re-write multiple same one line div's in html?

Tags: html

I'm have a html code, like this:

```
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
```

Is it a good way to write it like this? Maybe is there some more proper way instead of writing all the time the same divs and spans?

Comment: Not with HTML alone; need to add scripts

Comment: Really don't understand the question, tell us what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is static, you can't generate divs without them appearing in the final source code.
You can use back-end/front-end languages to generate the code automatically but eventually the browser will need to render this HTML.

If you want to avoid writing the classes for each div and span you can wrap them in a containing div and set only one class.

```css
.container div {
  // rules from filter-condition class
}

.container span {
  // rules from price class
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> Class1 <span> Span1 </span> </div>
  <div> Class1 <span> Span2 </span> </div>
  <div> Class1 <span> Span2 </span> </div>
  <div> Class1 <span> Span3 </span> </div>
  <div> Class1 <span> Span4 </span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only HTML, it is as simple as writing everything exactly how you want it to be. Therefore this would be impossible. However, you can use a backend language that will output HTML to make it simpler.

A common web backend language would be PHP. With a PHP file you could type in the following.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span<?= $i; ?> </span> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This would output.

```
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
```

If you have 5 classes as well, and need 25 total spans, you could nest two separate PHP For Loops, as shown below.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) { ?>
    <?php for ($x = 1; $x < 6; $x++) { ?>
        <div class="filter-condition"> Class<?= $i; ?> <span class="price"> Span<?= $x; ?> </span> </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This would output

```
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class2 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class2 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class2 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class2 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class2 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class3 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class3 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class3 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class3 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class3 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class4 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class4 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class4 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class4 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class4 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class5 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class5 <span class="price"> Span2 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class5 <span class="price"> Span3 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class5 <span class="price"> Span4 </span> </div>
<div class="filter-condition"> Class5 <span class="price"> Span5 </span> </div>
```

If you want to avoid using PHP, you can use template engines that compile into plain HTML files. This can be useful for more complex templates.

You could also use Javascript to achieve this after the initial page load, although that would not be recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there's, You can do it easily using `JavaScript` inside your html code, for example:-

```
...
<div id="top">
</div>
<script>
    var line = '<div class="filter-condition"> Class1 <span class="price"> Span1 </span> </div>';
    var lines = line;
    var number_of_lines = 5;
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++){
        lines += line;
    }
    document.getElementById("top").innerHtml += lines;
</script>
...
```

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, although I can see why it would be downvoted. Adding elements to the DOM like that after page load is not a recommended way of creating static HTML pages such as this one.

Comment: Thank you I didn't think of that, I just wanted to find a way to do that.